# Using SharePoint 2013 STS in custom web services

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint 2013 web application using claim based authentication where identity provider is windows. There are some custom web services in a "sub-application" within SharePoint website in IIS. What we want is to make those custom web services claim aware. So that in custom web services we should know that who is the current logged in user in SharePoint, whether he is authenticated SP user or not etc.

When we access the custom web service using an AJAX Web Part then the web service know the current logged in user, but using a content query (XSLT) Web Part the web service shows Application Pool's user as current logged in user, sort of double-hop problem.

Any idea how to fix this issue or how could I use the STS of SharePoint site in my custom web services application?